# Google Street View : Marker size and distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

I want to know if it is possible to set a size for the marker whatever the distance between it and the "camera" of Street View.

In the example, the marker is increasingly small if we move away :
http://jsfiddle.net/meneldil/7ygh1pva/

You will understand, I will wish that it still remains in its original size.

So, possible or not? :)

For information, `scaledSize` not working.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked [samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) on Google documentation and I observed that the marker's size (default size) doesn't change even if we zoom in or out. If you want to set the marker's size (bigger or smaller to its default), you can use an [icon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons) which defines an image. It defines the `size` of the icon, the `origin` of the icon (if the image you want is part of a larger image in a sprite, for example), and the `anchor` where the icon's hotspot should be located (which is based on the origin).

You can  use `scaledSize` instead of `size` as stated in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062849/modify-my-custom-marker-image-size-for-my-google-map):

> ```
> var image = {
>         url: '/Images/orange_guy.png', // image is 512 x 512
>         scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(22, 32)
>     };
> ```
>
> Working fiddle:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/556/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work... I change the code of @geocodezip, if you move away the icon is reduced : http://jsfiddle.net/meneldil/7ygh1pva/